# assign table values to recordset and update with another recordset using vb6

Tags: vb6

I want to assign database table columns to recordset in vb6. And i want update them with the values that i have in my another recordset. Is that possible?

How to assign the data from table to recordset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ADODB recordset is not a mirror of a database table.  The recordset contains whatever you want it to based on the query you provide it.  So to load the data from the database into the recordset you need to execute a query.  This can be done in two ways.

1. Use the `ADODB.Connection.Execute` method and set your recordset to the result.

```
Dim con as New ADODB.Connection  
Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset  
con.ConnectionString = "some connection string"  
con.Open  
Set rs = con.Execute("SELECT * FROM table")
```

2. Create an `ADODB.Recordset` object, specify the connection and then call the Open method passing it a query.

```
Dim con as New ADODB.Connection  
Dim rs as New ADODB.Recordset  
con.ConnectionString = "some connection string"  
con.Open  
Set rs.ActiveConnection = con  
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM table"
```

The query can be as simple or complex as you want it be.   The query could ask for fields from multiple tables and the recordset will still contain the results of the query, however you won't be able to tell which table the fields are from.

Answer (score 0):

A fabricated ADODB Recordset object is a fine container object because it has some great methods built in: `Filter`, `Sort`, `GetRows`, `GetString`, `Clone`, etc plus support for paging, serializing as XML, etc. For details see "Adding Fields to a Recordset" in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676135(VS.85).aspx).

But if you are working with database data, why not just execute a query?